# Google Apps Script - Wants to output a JSON, but got a HTML file on Postman

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have this portion of code. What it does is it gives the link of every image inside a Google drive directory and it gives a generated height and width. My problem is I wanted to return a JSON, but it returned an HTML. What should I change to get a JSON on POSTMAN

```
const doGet = (e) => {
  const pictures = getPictures();  
  return pictures;
}

const getPictures = () =>
{
    const destination_id = 'FOLDER FILE ID';  // ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECTORY;
    const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
    
    const files = destination.getFiles();
    const file_array = [];

    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      let file = files.next();
      let src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId()
      file_array.push({"src":src, "height":randomInteger(3,6), "width":randomInteger(3,6),});
    }
    console.log(file_array);

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(file_array)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}

const randomInteger = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

When clicking the web app URL, it shows me this **following image:**
[image]

But on postman, it gives me an HTML file like this:
[image]

Comment: From your showing image, about the setting of your Web Apps, I would like to ask you about the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`. And, you are using new IDE for the script editor of Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike: execute as "User acessing the web app", who has access "Only myself" and yes I am using new IDE for the script editor of Google Apps Script

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to the setting of your Web Apps. In this case, please modify the setting to `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`, and test it again. When `Who has access to the app: Only myself` is used, it is required to include your access token in the request header. I thought that by this, such an error occurs. [This report](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script) might be useful.

Comment: And also, now, I noticed that you are using the URL of developer mode. In this case, it is required to include your access token in the request header. So, in order to test your Web Apps using Postman without the access token, please use the URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` instead of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`. In this case, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps and test it again.

Comment: And, it seems that your Google Apps Script project belongs to the organization. In this case, it might confirm whether your Web Apps can be accessed from other domains. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Alright thanks, but is it normal I still have an HTML file on Postman instead of a JSON? I really need a JSON as output

Comment: If you will run your postman as a test, for the Web Apps URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`, how about requesting it including your access token in the request header? At that time, you can retrieve your access token as a sample by `const sample = _ => console.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())`. In your script, `DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id)` is included. So, I think that the scope can be used.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `Alright thanks, but is it normal I still have an HTML file on Postman instead of a JSON? I really need a JSON as output`, I couldn't confirm whether your Web Apps can be accessed from other domains. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes it could be accessed from other domains

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about using your access token for requesting to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Nope it doesn't work :(`, I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: It seems correct that on Postman it returns the full html since Postman does not interpret it. On web you see the json because the html is being rendered by the browswer. Does postman contain the information (the JSON) as well aside from the HTML code?

Comment: Have you changed the publishing settings as requested by Tanaike to `Anyone` and Execute as `me`?